# img not being uploaded via src tag

Tags: html, src

I can't figure out why my image is not loading when running the page. I know the issue lies inside the src tag and not defining where the project folder is but as far as my research around the src tag, this looks ok.

[image: html code]

Comment: Hello.  Please include the relevant code as part of your post, not a link to an image of code.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt actually in this case, the screenshot isn't such a bad idea, since next to the code it also shows the file structure and the location of the targeted file

Comment: Hi @Johannes.  That's fine, just didn't want a simple link in there is all so this user wouldn't get super down voted :-)

Answer (score 0):

Erase the `../`part at the beginning of the `src` attribute - the `images` folder is at the same level as your page. So it should be `src="images/white_nobelvel.png"`

Comment: ahh ok i thought since it was a seperate folder you have to still use the "../"

Thank you!